# Thicker lines and color in androidplot

Tags: android-studio

[image: wind graph]

I am using  androidplot in a wind application
I would like the lines at (as an example since they vary according to wind)
1,3,5,7 to make the horizontal lines different color (all 4 lines same color) and thicker.
For the series i use:

```
dynamicPlot.addSeries(SpeedSeries, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.BLUE, null, null));
```

I am using library androidplot-core-0.5.2.jar
A small piece of code will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to accomplish this would be to add markers.  For example, to add a red line for "3":

```
Paint markerPaint = new Paint();
markerPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
markerPaint.setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(4));  // line thickness
plot.addMarker(new YValueMarker(3, null, null, markerPaint, null));
```

Comment: this worked dynamicPlot.addMarker(new YValueMarker(
    7,                                         
    "Marker #2",                                // marker label
    new XPositionMetric(                        // object instance to set text positioning on the marker
      3,                                  // 3 pixel positioning offset
      XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT    // how/where the positioning offset is applied
    ),
    Color.BLUE,                                 // line paint color
    Color.BLUE                                  // text paint color
  ));